# $ionicDevice.ready() does not fire when building on linux

Tags: javascript, linux, cordova, ionic-framework, ready

I've been struggling wit this few days now and just can't work it out.

This is my `.run` part in `app.js` file located in the `www/js/` folder:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($rootScope, $state, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaDevice) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    alert( 'Platform ready!' );
    $rootScope.uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
    //$rootScope.$apply();
    alert( 'Uuid: ' + $rootScope.uuid );
  });
})
```

And this is my controller which takes the `$rootScope.uuid` and passes it to local `$scope.uuid` variable:

```
app.controller('RoomlistsCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $ionicModal, $sailsBind) {
  $scope.uuid = $rootScope.uuid;
});
```

which is used in form for adding new item on the list on server:

```
<input ng-model="newItem.uuid" type="hidden" value="{{ uuid }}">
```

The thing is, when i `ionic build android` on windows (on my work PC) everything works fine, i get the alert with `uuid` after the device is ready, BUT on my home PC (which runs Elementary 0.3 Freya) when i `ionic build android` the build goes well, everything seems to be ok but i dont get the alert after i run the app on android phone (4.2).

I have device plugin installed, this is output:

```
amotio@potato:~/git/my_project/mobile$ ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
running cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via plugin registry
Plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" already installed on android.
Saving plugin to package.json file
```

I've included dependency in `.run` function and as far as i know, everything is as supposed to be.

Does anyone know what can be the case here? I've trying to solve this for past 2 days, intensively, I've read almost everything from documentation (which still uses the old way of calling `ionic.Platform.ready()` - which i also tried without success, I've included `cordova.js` file just before `</body>` tag as someone mentioned in other stack question.

I'm glad for any help or lead that'll reveal what could be wrong, thank you.

Comment: Is `RoomlistsCtrl` the first view controller?

Comment: No it is not, before RoomlistsCtrl there is AppCtrl which does the same thing (to place the ID visibly to user so he knows his ID).
But as @aorfevre pointed out, the problem was in `window.cordova` &/or `window.StatusBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to setup the alert JUST after tje device ready instruction ?

Probably the issue is linked the the command above your first alert

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
```

Print out each value of window.cordova / window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard & window.StatusBar
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); or  StatusBar.styleDefault(); is probably sending that issue

Comment: Yes! Thank You! I did not though of deleting that line because it's there by default. I commented it out and problem was solved. Thank you so much :)